# Selecting delimited data in one column of data.table based on positional values in another

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table

```
x<-data.table(col1=rep("hello,how,are,you",4),col2=1:4)
              col1 col2
1: hello,how,are,you    1
2: hello,how,are,you    2
3: hello,how,are,you    3
4: hello,how,are,you    4
```

now I need to select values from col1 based on the values in col2. How can I do this within j of data.table?

Final data should look something like this

```
                 col1 col2   col3
1: hello,how,are,you    1    hello
2: hello,how,are,you    2    how
3: hello,how,are,you    3    are
4: hello,how,are,you    4    you
```

Comment: Are col1 words always separated by a comma in your real dataset too ?

Comment: You probably want to have a look at the `strplit()` function and either loop over rows, or use an `apply()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most efficient (is speed or memory the top concern?) solution:

```
library(data.table)
x <- data.table(col1=c(rep("hello,how,are,you",3), 
                       "Lirum, Larum, Löffel, Stiel"),
                col2=1:4)
x[, ind := .I]
x[, col3 := strsplit(col1, ",", fixed=TRUE)]
x[, col4 := col3[[1]][col2], by=ind]

#                           col1 col2 ind                        col3   col4
# 1:           hello,how,are,you    1   1           hello,how,are,you  hello
# 2:           hello,how,are,you    2   2           hello,how,are,you    how
# 3:           hello,how,are,you    3   3           hello,how,are,you    are
# 4: Lirum, Larum, Löffel, Stiel    4   4 Lirum, Larum, Löffel, Stiel  Stiel
```

Comment: Thanks Roland, this is exactly what I wanted, can you tell me why u used by=ind. if I don't use "by=ind" it's as if there is only one element in the list which is "hello,how,are,you". Maybe the question is confusing, let me clarify , from what I know if an explicit by statement is not provided data.table will keep the data intact ie a single group, am i wrong here?

Comment: `by=ind` does operations by each group of unique values in `ind`. Since `ind` is a row index, the operation is done for each row (i.e., this is a faster equivalent to `apply(x, 1, somefun)`)

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option, that combines the result of `strsplit` into a matrix and then uses matrix subsetting:

```
x <- data.table(col1=rep("hello,how,are,you",4),col2=1:4)

x[, col3 := do.call(rbind, strsplit(col1, split = ",", fixed = TRUE))
               [matrix(c(1:.N, col2), ncol = 2)]]
x
#                col1 col2  col3
#1: hello,how,are,you    1 hello
#2: hello,how,are,you    2   how
#3: hello,how,are,you    3   are
#4: hello,how,are,you    4   you
```

Comment: this won't work if the delimited data is not rectangular

Answer (score 1):

I hope following can work for you...

Solution 1 : if col1 don't have fixed word length

```
col1 = c(paste(c('hello','how','are','you'),1,sep='-',collapse=','),
         paste(c('hello','how','are','you'),2,sep='-',collapse=','),
         paste(c('hello','how','are','you'),3,sep='-',collapse=','),
         paste(c('hello','how','are','you'),4,sep='-',collapse=','))

x<-data.table(col1=col1,col2=1:4)
x$col3 = NA
for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  x$col3[i] = strsplit(x$col1[i],',')[[1]][x$col2[i]]
}
```